# Defining a Root Path

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm looking for a way to define a config variable as being the root path of my website. What's the nicest way to define this. I am using Codeigniter.

```
$config['root_path'] = ?
```

This is for my site_config file in my config folder.

```
/
/dev
/dev/application
/dev/application
/dev/application/config
/dev/application/config/site_config.php
/dev/system/
/dev/assets/
/public_html
```

Comment: Please clarify what the "root path" in this case should be, maybe with an example.

Comment: Updated for you. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Does the root_path variable need to contain the public_html part?

Comment: No because I have a dev sub domain and the public_html which is to production so im going to use the root variable to decide which to go into at a later time so I just need it to go into the furthest directory

Comment: I don't understand your problem here. Is the root_path the root html folder? or is it the root of your codeigniter application? The way it should work is if you have 2 sites, then you need to set your virtual hosts to point to different pathtowebroot/index.php as index.php is the one defining the paths to your application folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
$config['root_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

will give you what you're looking for, regardless of which script calls it from where.

On the other hand, I have approximately zero experience with codeigniter, which could negatively impact the efficacy of my suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

I usually use `__DIR__`. For example, if your configuration file is in the root directory you can use:

```
$config['root_path']=__DIR__;
```

Or if it's in a subdirectory of the project (for example `/anyframework/config/config.php`):

```
$config['root_path']=dirname(dirname(__DIR__));
```

Comment: I'm thinking that will only return the directory of the script itself though. Won't it?

Comment: It will return the directory of the PHP file the constant is used in. So if the configuration file lies in the root directory of the project, this will work. If the configuration file is somewhere down the tree you can add as many dirnames() as needed to go up.

Comment: Op mentioned codeigniter, if you follow the flow of how codeigniter works, then the directory returned would be minimal 2 directories up from root. and would be `/application/config/`. OP appears to want absolute path from root. `/home/name/public_html/`

Comment: Don't know anything about CodeIgniter, but if the file defining `$config` is in `/application/config` then `dirname(dirname((__DIR__))` should work.