# how to download a file from server using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my project I need to use `$_SERVER['document_root']` to download files from my server.

`$_server['document_root']` returns `home/webuser/public_html` and my picture folder is in `home/webuser/public_html/testProjet/pics/`

How can I get this done?

Comment: simple add <?php echo $_SERVER['document_root'] . '/testProjet/pics/'; ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php):

```
realpath('pics/'.$filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

please use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` ,

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/testProjet/pics/'.$filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this - **root_path**, reference link - [Defining a Root Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754349/defining-a-root-path)

```
function download_file ($user_id, $file_row_id)
{
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $name = $this->model->download_file($user_id, $file_row_id);

    output_file(ROOT_PATH. 'images/user/uploaded_files/' . $name['uploaded_file_name'], $name['original_file_name'], '', true);
}
```